# use dynamically selected array in function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to get the value of an element when clicked, I would then like to use that to match which array to use in a bootstrap typeahead later in the script. so for example:

```
var use = [];

$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').on("click", function() {
    use = $(this).data('name');
    alert(use);
});
```

if the data-name attribute selected is "cat" than the "use" variable would equal "cat" and we have a "cat" array:

```
var cat = [
    {val: 'res', string: "Residential"},
    {val: 'Dup', string: "Duplexes & Apartments"},
    {val: 'Con', string: "Condominiums"},
    {val: 'Lot', string: "Lots, Land & Farms"},
    {val: 'Com', string: "Commercial"},
    {val: 'Mob', string: "Mobile Homes"},
];
```

and then this is where I am not sure how to handle this. instead of using "cat" in the below function, I would like to replace "cat" with whatever function matches what is data-name selected above.

```
$('#input-tag').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
            var results = _.map(cat, function(value) {
                return value.val;
            });
            process(results);
    }
});
```

I hope I explained this right. I think I'm a bit over my head tonight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object where the key is the data source(e.g. cat) and the value is an array:

```
var obj = {
   "cat" :  [
    {val: 'res', string: "Residential"},
    {val: 'Dup', string: "Duplexes & Apartments"},
    {val: 'Con', string: "Condominiums"},
    {val: 'Lot', string: "Lots, Land & Farms"},
    {val: 'Com', string: "Commercial"},
    {val: 'Mob', string: "Mobile Homes"}
],
   "dog": [ {val: 'res', string: 'Dunno' }]
};
```

And then you can fetch the correct array this way:

```
var data = $(this).data('name'); // 'cat';
var catArr = obj[data];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Coincidentally cat is short for category lol ;)